# Switching between textures on the same model

Tags: gltf

I'm generating a GLTF file that will contain multiple possible textures for the same model, with the same texture coordinates. In GLTF, I can only choose one of these textures as active for the mesh (as far as I know). For example, the model would have the texture of flames as default. But there would be a texture of grass available too. Is there any way Blender would be able to switch between these two?

Comment: There are many ways to switch textures: switch material, have a single texture with different islands and switch UVs, have a factor controlled shader mix node switching between different node groups... I'd suggest to learn about Shader Nodes and how to use textures.

Comment: There's a work-in-progress glTF extension being developed to handle this, but the spec isn't final yet.  Feedback welcome!  https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/pull/1681

Comment: Thanks @Bruno, I'll have a look.I'm not very familiar with blender, which one of these would be the easiest to switch from the user's point of view? So that they don't have to search for a thousand submenus and options.

Comment: You could have a mix shader and animate or add keys on the mix shader factor.